# Свой сервис регистрации доменов

Tags: php, домен

Стоит задача создать свой собственный сервис регистрации доменов. Вопрос в следующем: есть ли web-ресурсы, предоставляющие API для регистрации доменов? Или вообще хоть какие-нибудь ресурсы. Вообщем в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Leehost.ru регистрирует домены через reg.ru , сам их услугами по регистрации пользуюсь.

Comment: Большой всем Вам сенкъю, господа) Приобретать я ничего не хочу. Мне нужен лишь API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Многие регистраторы предоставляют API для автоматической регистрации. Например, netfox: [API-интерфейсы для регистрации доменов](http://www.netfox.ru/domains/api/). Можно искать по словам: api регистрации доменов.

Comment: Цены не могу найти!)

Answer (score 2):

reg.ru Предоставляет такую возможность. Есть даже софт :) http://software.reg.ru/

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите тут к примеру http://www.naunet.ru/r/partners/collaborate/reseller/.

А вот и цены у них: http://www.naunet.ru/tools/origin/domain-partners/ru/

Comment: Можно в гугле искать по ключевым словам reseller domain register скорее всего, ну или по русски.

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть собственная панелька RegService.NET, если есть желание приобрести, расскажу подробно где что и как управляется, а так же проведу по красной ковровой дорожке в доменный бизнес) 
Сам сервис берёт API на reg.ru, очень удобно!